# Combine two lists in Ansible

Tags: list, ansible

I have a list1:

```yaml
     "list1": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "b"
                },  
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "c"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "d"
                }
               ]
```

and also a list2:

```yaml
     "list2": [
                {
                    "id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4"
                }
               ]
```

what I need is a list3 that will look like this:

```yaml
      "list3": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "d"
                },
               ]
```

So, list3 need to have both id and name but only in case there is a match between id's in lists 1 and 2.

With this:

```yaml
    list3: "{{ list1 | combine(list2) }}"
```

I get:

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": {
> "id": "4",
> "name": "d"
> }

but that's not what I want.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want to filter a list rather than combine it.

Comment: => `{{ list1 | selectattr('id', 'in', list2 | map(attribute='id')) }}`

Comment: Thank you, I will change the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list3: "{{ list1 | selectattr('id', 'in', list2 | map(attribute='id')) }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{list3}}"
```

That gives result:

```
ok: [localhost] => { "msg": [ { "id": "1", "name": "a" }, { "id": "4", "name": "d" } ] }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).